# Contrasting theorems in classical logic and constructivism

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, big-list, examples, constructive-mathematics

1. Is it possible there are examples of where classical logic proves a theorem that provably is false within constructivism? Is so what are some examples?
2. What are some examples of most contrasting theorems provable in these two logics that does not fall in 1.?

Comment: Relevant, I think, are [Brouwerian counterexamples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof#Brouwerian_counterexamples). There are also no doubt many examples such as the following: [Osvald Demuth](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.4449.pdf), [*The differentiability of constructive functions*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=263628) (Russian, 1969). The MR review begins: "An increasing constructive function $[\cdots]$ on the constructive interval $[0,1]$ is given which $[\cdots]$ is nowhere differentiable."

Comment: Brouwerian counterexamples are mostly good for convincing classical mathematicians that intuitionism makes no sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very natural question, but as it happens one needs some more background to give a natural answer (is my humble opinion).

For clarity let me give a summary first indication:

As to your **Question 1.** : This is commonly thought of as not being possible in strict terms, because '*constructive mathematics*' is usually interpreted as '*that part of alternative constructive mathematical theories which is compatible with classical mathematics*.'

Broadly speaking, this interpretation of 'constructive mathematics' is known as BISH (from Bishop-style mathematics). BISH is seen as the common core of classical math (CLASS), 
intuitionistic mathematics (INT) and 'Russian' recursive mathematics a la Markov (RUSS).

Now if we include INT and RUSS in your term 'constructivism'. then the answer to question 1. is yes.

This because both INT and RUSS have additional axioms (compared to BISH) that are false classically. You could equally say that CLASS has an additional axiom compared to BISH (namely excluded middle) that is provably false in INT and RUSS.

Famous examples of conflicting theorems are:

a) All total functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are continuous (a theorem both in INT and RUSS)

b) The unit interval is compact in the Heine-Borel sense (a theorem both in CLASS and INT, but false in RUSS).

[Finally, if perhaps you mean only propositional first-order logic, then the answer is no again, because usually the term 'intuitionistic logic' is used to indicate that part of classical propositional logic which is valid constructively, which you can think of as `the part without excluded middle'.]

In the comment above, Brouwerian counterexamples are mentioned. Brouwerian counterexamples are explicit constructive examples where we can demonstrate that the classical 'solution' has insufficient constructive content (no general algorithm possible, or some other constructive deficiency). Often, Brouwerian counterexamples can be generalized to conflicting theorems in INT and/or RUSS. Brouwerian counterexamples are often useful in BISH to indicate that there can be little hope of constructivizing a certain classical theorem.

---

[Update 29 March | After your elucidation in the comments below, I feel I can give:]

Some remarks for **Question 2**:

a) An important example concerns axioms of choice. In constructivism (BISH, INT, RUSS) there are a number of choice axioms which may or may not conflict with each other and/or CLASS, depending on the precise phrasing and of course the intended logical strength.

In general, constructivists do not dismiss all forms of the idea that the statement *for all $x$ there is $y$ such that $P(x,y)$* implies the existence of a choice function $f$ such that $P(x, f(x))$ holds for all $x$.

But the difference with CLASS (or between the others) can still be quite sharp, because of the very different interpretation of what is a 'meaningful' statement.

For a constructivist, 'meaningful' usually implies that we are talking about mathematical structures that can be constructed *like* (and therefore *from* !) the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, if we give ourselves enough time to do so. (Strict finitism is also a field of study in constructive mathematics, but since this is quite difficult it has not attracted many researchers).

In classical mathematics, a theory is often considered 'meaningful' already if we have good reason to believe that the theory is consistent. Whether the theory describes structures that we can actually build from scratch (viz. $\mathbb{N}$) is often not a matter of interest.

Strong intuitionistic axioms of choice sometimes expose this huge philosophical difference by leading to theorems which are false in CLASS, but sometimes they also lead to INT having the 'same' theorem as in CLASS (and you can only tell the difference by carefully interpreting the difference in meaning).

b) Another important example (also) concerns 'information' and 'interpretation'. Very very often, contradiction between CLASS and INT or RUSS can be meaningfully avoided by rephrasing. For example, by changing 'for all $x$' (CLASS) into 'for all $x$ for which we can determine whether $x\geq 0$ or $x\leq 0$' (INT), we might obtain the 'same' theorem.

This is imho a most salient point that Bishop added to Brouwer's views: why look for contradiction if you can rephrase for accordance?

However, imho it can also be very clarifying to study these contradictions. Usually one learns better how to rephrase for accordance when one has a clear idea where the conflict arises...

Comment: This answer is spot on! I'd like to contribute the realizability topos given by infinite-time Turing machines as a further intriguing environment. Any topos has an "internal logic", but the one of this one is particularly challenges many mathematical intuitions shaped by classical logic. In this topos, there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ (as you would expect from CLASS), but there is an injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$. [This observation is due to Andrej Bauer.](http://math.andrej.com/2011/06/15/constructive-gem-an-injection-from-baire-space-to-natural-numbers/)

Comment: (a) comes from the fact that the equality of two real numbers is not decidable. (a) just means that there are less well-defined total functions in INT and RUSS than in CLASS.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt yes that is a nice addition. Am I correct in thinking that you mean an injection from Baire space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ into  $\mathbb{N}$? Perhaps this also leads to an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{N}$ but I don't see this immediately, being poorly knowledged on toposes.

Comment: @Franka I meant $\mathbb{R}$, but indeed now that you say it I recall that Andrej proved it for $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. Slides illustrating Andrej's proof are [here](https://rawgit.com/iblech/mathezirkel-kurs/master/superturingmaschinen/slides-warwick2017.pdf) (see slide 24/25). The argument easily adapts to $\mathbb{R}$, this is a fun exercise; if you want me to spell out the details, I'll gladly do so!

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt on principle i would of course like to try it myself... but wisdom or (rather more likely) experience tells me i'd be very happy if you would spell it out for me :-) . do you have my email address?

Comment: @Franka Thank you for providing motivation! I just added the proof to [a paper draft](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/paper-filmat.pdf) of mine, please have a look at Footnote 9 in Section 2.2 and share any difficulties in following the argument so that I can improve it, for the benefit of all who are interested in this curious injection. :-) Section 2 of this paper aims to give a leisurely introduction to the internal language of the effective topos and is hopefully readable even without extensive knowledge of toposes.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt thanks Ingo! It will take me some time to read ( 27 pages...:-) ) but I will do my best and get back to you. Cheers Franka

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk For 2 I meant even if you do not get total contradiction like true and false perhaps we can get something that does not imply other under reasonable considerations or even perhaps contradicts other under reasonable considerations.

Comment: @VS. After your explanation I added some remarks on question 2. to my answer. The remarks are a bit generic, because specific examples would take too much detail (thus obscuring clarity for non-insiders). Hope you still can get the gist, if not I could try to specify a bit more.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk For Pi_2^0 statements such contradiction cannot occur (that is true in classical and false in constructive) by cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-March/010113.html. How about for Sigma_2^0 statements which can be shown to be true in classical nevertheless false in constructive? Perhaps it is possible to prove P=NP in classical and P\neq NP in constructive.

Comment: @VS. Your remark concerns Peano Arithmetic PA only...outside of PA there are many $\forall\exists$ statements which are true in CLASS but not in INT and/or RUSS, or vice versa. It so happens that P=NP is equivalent to a $\Pi_0^2$ statement so in that particular case INT and CLASS will agree.

Comment: The terminology seems quite confusing! If I've understood right: when discussing mathematics, 'intuitionistic' contradicts 'classical' while 'constructive' is a weakening of both; but for logics, 'intuitionistic' is a weakening of 'classical'?

Comment: This is partly a common situation in axiomatics... when we drop Euclid's fifth postulate, we get a weakening of Euclidean geometry. This weakening then allows us to add a non-parallelity axiom to obtain a non-Euclidean geometry which is contradictory to what we started with. Similarly intuitionistic first-order logic allows us to add non-classical axioms to obtain either full-blown  INT or RUSS, which are contradictory to CLASS. Not adding these axioms gives us BISH, say. Historically Brouwer was by far the first (INT), which is why the terms intuitionistic and constructive get mixed.

Comment: @RobinSaunders : see above... (couldn't add your tag because to do so exceeded the text limit)

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk FYI P\neq NP is \Pi^0_2 statement while P=NP is \Sigma^0_2 statement. So I still dont follow if P=NP is possible in Classical while P\neq NP is possible without LEM or LLPO? Also note P\neq NP in Classical implies P\neq NP without LEM or LLPO since P\neq NP is a \Pi^0_2 statement.

Comment: No, this is not possible. PA is conservative over Heyting Arithmetic HA (which is PA without excluded middle) with respect to $\Pi_0^2$ statements.  PA proving P$\neq$NP implies that already HA proves P$\neq$NP.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk Ok.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk If a statement is provable then is it necessarily in Sigma1? I think that will resolve my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

There are several ways one could interpret the word "constructivism" here, and the answer depends on what you meant by it.

**Bishop-style constructivism** is a *generalization* of Brouwerian intuitionistim, Russian constructivism, and classical mathematics. It is mathematics done without excluded middle (of course, you can still use excluded middle on those instances that you can prove to hold using other means) and general axiom of choice, but you still have countable choice. Thus, anything you prove in this setting is true in classical mathematics as well.

There are other forms of constructivism which are Bishop-style constructivism *extended with* additional principles and axioms. These additional principles often contradict classical logic, and so you get consequences that are classically false. Here are some examples:

In the internal language of the effective topos (an older name for this is **Russian constructivism**) the following are valid statements:

1. There are countably many countable subset of $\mathbb{N}$.
2. There is an increasing sequence in $[0,1]$ that has no accumulation point.
3. The Cantor space $2^\mathbb{N}$ and the Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ are homeomorphic.
4. Every map $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
5. There exists a continuous unbounded map $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.
6. There is a covering of $\mathbb{R}$ by intervals $(a_n, b_n)_n$ with rational endpoints such that $\sum_{k = 1}^n |b_n - a_n| < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
7. There is a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ which is not finite and not infinite.
8. There exists an infinite binary rooted tree in which every path is finite.
9. The ordinals form a set, i.e., they are not a proper class. One has to be careful about how ordinals are defined and how to precisely understand the notions of "class" and "set", but these are technical details.

In the internal language of the realizability topos $\mathsf{RT}(K_2)$ (an older name for this is **Brouwerian intuitionisism**) the following statements are valid:

1. Every map $f : X \to Y$ between complete separable metric spaces is continuous.
2. Every map $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.
3. Every map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}$ is constant, or equivalently, if $\mathbb{R} = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A = \mathbb{R}$ or $B = \mathbb{R}$.

There are many other examples. I recommend taking the effort to get used to these amazing new worlds of mathematics.

Comment: What do the applied mathematicians say about these outrageous statements?

Comment: I don't think they know about them, or at least I never got a reaction. There's a positive side to all of this, too. For example, in the effective topos everything is computable (in a precise sense). I'd imagine at least some applied mathematicians would appreciate that. In general, I find computer scientists will take anything that helps them solve their problems, even if it's outrageous. Mathematicians are more hung up on value judgements and respecting traditions.

Comment: Oh, there's another topos (a model of intuitionistic bounded Zermelo set theory) that would interest applied mathematicians. In it all maps are differentiable and nilpotent infinitesimals exist, so you get to do analysis engineering-style, with $dx$'s and $dy$'s that are very small and whose squares are negligible.

Comment: What would you say to the typical high school math teacher who says many of these statements can be disproven by drawing a picture? They are so antithetical to geometric and physical intuition.

Comment: They are only antithetical to geometric and physical intuition under one understanding of "space" and "continuity" – the one you are aware of. It is entirely possible to develop different kinds of intuition (speaking from first-hand experience and having taught PhD students the alternatives) that let you "internalize" these statements. So, it's really the high-school teachers who determine what kind of intuitions the young minds will develop. In the current educational system there is only one kind. The resulting uniformity of thought gives the illusion of absolute truth.

Comment: Perhaps the closest we get in practice to alternative geometric intuitions is when engineers and physicsts, despite having been taught $\epsilon\delta$ proofs, insist on using infinitesimals. They don't have the necessary formal training to use them properly (because they were taught $\epsilon\delta$ proofs), but they rely on their intuitions quite reliably.

Comment: And by the way, it's not always about logic and foundations. One can change define "space" (in ZFC) in such a way that Banach-Tarski goes away and all subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable, and the definition is arguably  *simpler* than the usual definition of topological space (but of course one needs to get used to it, as is usual with new math). See for instance [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2011.12.014) by Alex Simpson.

Comment: Just briefly, here is an alternative high-school explanation of why all maps are continuous: motion is continuous, obviously, since if I want to get from $A$ to $B$ I cannot just teleport (despite many sci-fi movies). Therefore, all functions $\mathsf{Time} \to \mathsf{Space}$ are continuous. We can also have teleportation, but then we need to modify $\mathsf{Time}$ to account for it.

Comment: It seems like you have to bite the bullet.  A lot of things I can draw on the board that are usually meant to represent geometrical shapes or functions on $\mathbb R$ cannot represent the “real” mathematical things according to constructive math (i.e. discontinuous but piecewise continuous functions, or anything inducing such a function like a Euclidean shape).  Pedagogically this sounds like a nightmare.  Or maybe if people are interested in studying things corresponding to “classical” intuition, then you have to convince them to study finitary surrogates for those?

Comment: *What would you say to the typical high school math teacher who says many of these statements can be disproven by drawing a picture?* You can't really draw a discontinuous, total function, for example. No matter how accurately you try to draw it, you'll either leave a gap in the domain or make the pieces overlap, so that it's not a function. *They are so antithetical to geometric and physical intuition.* My physical intuition differs from yours. My physical intuition is that any time I see a discontinuous function, it's an idealized mathematical fiction, not physical reality.

Comment: *[Physicists] don't have the necessary formal training to use [infinitesimals] properly (because they were taught ϵδ proofs), but they rely on their intuitions quite reliably.* The type of reasoning you see in these calculations is all first-order logic, so it's correct by the transfer principle, or can be made so by trivial changes such a changing "neglecting $dx$..." to "taking the standard part..."

Comment: @MonroeEskew: a piecewise continuous map, say $f(x) = \mathsf{if}\; x < 0 \;\mathsf{then}\; 0 \;\mathsf{else}\; 1$ has as its domain the set $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < 0 \lor x \geq 0\}$. The strange thing is, that constructively $D$ is a *proper* subset of $\mathbb{R}$, even though $\mathbb{R} \setminus D = \emptyset$. It's a phenomenon that is difficult to explain classically. It's not that $D$ has fewer points than $\mathbb{R}$. Rather, the points of $D$  have *more information*. Each point of $D$ comes with information on whether it is negative or non-negative.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I think your criticism is not entirely fair. Of course one can never draw a completely accurate graph of a discontinuous function – but the same holds for *any* graph, because pencils are not infinitely thin. As Monroe says, it's better to just bite the bullet and try to understand how it's possible to have a proper subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D = \emptyset$. Once you get over that hurdle, a lot fo constructive math starts to make more sense.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I think physicists tend to use something closer to nilpotent infinitesimals of synthetic differential geometry (SDG), rather than non-standard analysis. They say things like "we may ignore $dx^2$", which directly translates to "$dx$ is a square-nilpotent" in SDG. (Of course, there's still a lot of similarity with non-standard analysis.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Is this the right way to understand it?  If you want to treat classical analysis (or just undergrad calculus) in a way that doesn’t diverge too dramatically from common notions, but is still faithful to constructivism, then you do a kind of calculus of partial functions, where the domains tend to shrink as you introduce more information about the definitions of the functions.  So classical analysis is about “something” that is just a lot harder to describe from the constructivist standpoint?

Comment: Perhaps a reasonable analogy can be take from topology: let $R_d$ be the reals with the discrete topology and $R_e$ the reals with Euclidean topology. The identity map $\mathrm{id} : R_d \to R_e$ is a continuous injection, so $R_d$ is a "subspace" of $R_e$ (not what topologists would say). It's this sort of thing that's going on.

Comment: If you want to do classical analysis, then it's best to use classical logic. You *can* do classical analysis constructively, but it will be clumsy and unnatural. The situation is symmetric: you *can* do constructive math in classical logic by "simulating" then using models, but that's a lot of overhead.

Comment: @AndrejBauer In Riemannian geometry we add a point at infinity to compactify the plane. Is it known that proofs that essentially utilize compacitification are non-constructive and cannot be constructivized? That is there is no proof in the sense that HA cannot prove it but PA can if we cannot avoid compactification?

Comment: It is "essentially known" that the vast majority of mathematics is constructive, or can be constructivized. Specifically, there should be no trouble with one-point compactifications. You're a bit off there with HA and PA, as those are not strong enough to talk about analysis. You'd want a richer formalism.